# How to troubleshot an asus rt-n66u dark night router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt, tomato

I have an Ausus rt-n66u with tomatusb firmware( 2 years old version) that stopped working .Wifi is down and ethernet access to the administration page is not working.
What are my options ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried connecting thru `ssh`?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the router?

Comment: I tried to connect using SSH , no answer. I tried to reset the router but no change.